# how to remove default status of Selectbox/Checkbox?

Tags: html, css, web

I'd like to know, how to remove default arrow of selectbox and gradations in Checkbox and I wanna use custom image on it.

for example, here is some code.

```
 <select class="selectParent">
     <option value='1'>Title</option>
     <option value='2'>Description</option> 
     <option value='3'>Author</option>
 </select>
```

I searched some solutions to remove default status using -webkit- appearance; and -moz- appearance; but I have no idea in IE. Is there any possibility to remove a default status in IE?

as a same logic, I'd like to know, how to remove default status in checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="category" id="category10"/>
```

I'll be wating for good answers thx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`appearance: none` would work, but [this is not a cross-browser way to do it](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/).

```
select, input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pKWCN/)

### EDIT:

Here is a cross-browser method for checkbox,

http://jsfiddle.net/kyLq4/1/

Comment: As I said it doesn't work for opera and ie. http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/

Comment: which means, there is no idea for ie?

Comment: There is no such a way to do that in IE, you should create your own select tag with html. Look at my updated answer for checkbox.

Answer (score 5):

This is currently possible in all browsers except Opera (although that should work when it switches to Blink).

For Firefox and WebKit/Blink, you need to use `appearance: none;`, which is fairly heavy handed and removes all styling:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

You can also include the prefixless version if you wish, although the appearance property is no longer in any standard. It was dropped from [CSS3 Basic UI](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui/).

For IE, you can specifically style the check mark by using the -ms-check pseudo element. If you'd like to just hide the checkmark you can do the following:

```
input[type="checkbox"]::-ms-check {
    color: transparent;
}
```

If you want to hide the entire element, like what `appearance: none;` does, you can do:

```
input[type="checkbox"]::-ms-check {
    display: none;
}
```

To add the check mark back, you should use the `:checked` pseudo class:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Here is a demo using the latter approach. I've just set the background color when checked, but you can just as easily use an image: http://jsfiddle.net/HxqKu/3/

Comment: This fiddle does not work in IE9 - see screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/1dvufxrm0ppkfcd/Screenshot%202016-05-26%2017.22.22.png?dl=0