# Read More in PURE CSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Trying to implement a CSS read more code using ONLY CSS with NO JavaScript involved. Here is the html:

```css
.has-read-more {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

.has-read-more div {
  height: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.show-more {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 140%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: -20%;
}

.show-more:after {
  content: "read more";
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, white);
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

.show-more span {
  background: white
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+div {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="has-read-more">
  <input type="checkbox" class="show-more">
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sit amet ornare odio, at cursus nisi. Suspendisse sodales ante mollis posuere finibus. Sed erat nibh, efficitur vitae venenatis sit amet, ornare et ligula. Suspendisse hendrerit nulla
      quam, at hendrerit justo lacinia quis. Nunc nec dui in enim suscipit egestas et ut augue.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sit amet ornare odio, at cursus nisi. Suspendisse sodales ante mollis posuere finibus. Sed erat nibh, efficitur vitae venenatis sit amet, ornare et ligula. </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sit amet ornare odio, at cursus nisi. Suspendisse sodales ante mollis posuere finibus. Sed erat nibh, efficitur vitae venenatis sit amet, ornare et ligula. Suspendisse hendrerit nulla
      quam, at hendrerit justo lacinia quis. Nunc nec dui in enim suscipit egestas et ut augue.</p>
    <p>Sed erat nibh, efficitur vitae venenatis sit amet, ornare et ligula. Suspendisse hendrerit nulla quam, at hendrerit justo lacinia quis. Nunc nec dui in enim suscipit egestas et ut augue.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

It all works apart from the checkbox appearing and not being replaced by read more text (which has its own background).

I have read other similar stack threads including this one: [How to implement Read more / Read less in pure CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968211/how-to-implement-read-more-read-less-in-pure-css) but not looking to implement one that has read more/read less as that has.

The one I am working with works apart from that last bit. I must be a bit stupid as I just cannot seem to figure out why the checkbox is not replaced with the text.

It needs to be a purse CSS solution and not one based on JS. I have tried using a label but it gets appended to the beginning of the text box and not inline with the checkbox.

What do I seem to be doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you just have to [remove the checkbox style in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16350273/1650337).

Comment: I'm confused as to why the question you've linked to doesn't answer your question. If you don't want to have the "read less" functionality, just set `display: none` on the `read-more-trigger` when its checkbox is checked.

Comment: @DBS tried removing those background/border/outline/shadow and set to none but that doesnt do anything.

Comment: @Umbrella Yep, I updated that comment after realising I was talking rubbish. Have a look at the link that's there now.

Comment: @HereticMonkey because that one wraps the text in a slightly different manner. With the code on an existing page it doesnt work as effectivly as the code I posted the markup to me looks a little more than whats required...

Comment: @DBS aha so simple. works on the fiddle as expected now. Only problem is going to be that all inputs will have the appearence:none now which on a live site wont be workable. how can I target just the input in this code only? sorry not an expert when it comes to things like this

Comment: @DBS never mind! figured it out. thanks for your quick input. saved me a few hours of faffing around not to mention pulling my hair out. Just targetted the input like this:  input.show-more